# Страница не загружена jQuery

Tags: jquery

когда страница готова все просто:
    $(document).ready();
а если мне нужно узнать когда страница не готова?

Я хочу сделать: когда уже страница загружена(!) при нажатии ссылки выдавать гифку загрузки.
Мне нужно узнать когда страница еще не изменилась, но загрузка другой пошла...

Всем ссылкам делать событие думаю глупо...

Comment: Сделайте событие для body которое начинает крутить спиннер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не совсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать.

Узнать, когда текущая страница начала выгружаться можно с помощью события `window.onunload`. Однако как только начнется загрузка следующей страницы, *бразуер уничтожит предыдущую вместе со всеми значками, элементами и кодом* и ваш значёк загрузки пропадёт. Фактически, таким способом вы отобразите его на долю секунды.

**Чтобы реализовать то, что вы хотите**, вам необходимо загружать страницы с помощью **AJAX** *не уничтожая текущую страницу*. Если вы загружаете страницы по ссылкам с помощью AJAX (т.е. JavaScript запросом), то можно сделать следующее.

1. Пользователь нажимает ссылку, вызывается ваш JavaScript-обработчик этого события.
2. Вы *показываете значёк загрузки*, затем начинаете саму загрузку с помощью AJAX (конкретно в jQuery — `$.get`, `$.post`, `$.ajax` и тому подобное).
3. По завершении загрузки в функции-обработчике вы, кроме всего прочего, *убираете значёк загрузки* и *заменяете* старое содержмое страницы вновь полученным.

Костыль, но лучше пока ничего реализовать не получится.

Comment: Да, мне и нужно на ту долю секунды! Я тут немного експерементирую и мне видимо надо именно window.onunload

Comment: и где можно почитать о window.onunload? Если есть ссылку. буду очень благодарен

Comment: @myvzar, например, [вот](http://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror#window-onunload).

Сущесвтует так же событие `window.onbeforeunload`, но оно не гарантировано кросс-браузерное.